# Edge that allows a follower to take any wounds a Wild Card receives

Tags: savage-worlds

Somewhere I remember seeing a Boss Edge where it could sacrifice a follower to take any wounds he receives. Can someone tell me where I read it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that this was an Edge? *Savage Worlds Deluxe* has the "Fanatics" setting rule in Chapter 4's "Setting Rules" section, which allows a villain to have one of their underlings take a wound for them. This does not apply to player characters.

> ### Fanatics
>
> Use this rule in pulp-style games where villains are larger than life. When a Wild Card enemy character is hit by a successful attack, any of his henchmen, goons, or other allies jumps in front of his master and suffers the attack instead.

If you are sure it was an Edge, or that it was also available to players, there are a couple of possible candidates.

The [*Interface Zero 2.0*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/124685/Interface-Zero-20-Full-Metal-Cyberpunk) setting has a Professional Edge like this called "Bodyguard" (which is close to the name "Boss" that you remembered). It's slightly different though in that it has one character jump in front of another character, rather than one character choosing to sacrifice a follower.

> ### Bodyguard
>
> **Requirements:** Novice, Agility d8+, Fighting d8+, Notice d6+
>
> Bodyguards make their living by protecting someone else. This means they not only have to be aware of any potential dangers, but must be able to act quickly and effectively to prevent any harm from coming to their charge. A character with this Edge gains a +2 bonus to Notice checks made to detect potential ambushes or similar dangers. Additionally, the character may spend a Benny once per round to place himself in the way of any attack (Fighting, Shooting or Throwing) against a person within 5”. All Fighting rolls are then made against his Parry, and he suffers the effect of any successful attacks. This can be done at any time, regardless of the bodyguard’s Initiative, and counts as a free action; any other actions must be taken on his own initiative card.

[*Shaintar: Legends Arise*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/115010/Shaintar-Legends-Arise) has an Orc Racial Edge called "Defender of the Gather" that also allows a character to take the hit for someone else.

> ### Defender of the Gather
>
> **Requirements:** Novice, Orc, Spirit d6+, Fighting d8+
>
> The traditional role of orcs in goblinesh society is to defend their homesteads, a role many orcs still take very seriously. An orc with this Edge may, as a reaction to a successful hit against an ally, fling himself in the way and take the damage instead. The player must elect to do this before the damage is rolled, and he can only do this for allies that are within half his Pace. If he is wounded while performing this act of self-sacrifice, he gains a benny.

Also, your question title was originally titled "Rather you than me" before it was edited. This made me think of the [Adventure Deck](https://www.peginc.com/store/action-adventure-decks/) from Pinnacle, which has a card with a similar name called "Better You Than Me":

> ### Better You Than Me
>
> *"Fritz! They shot Fritz!"*
>
> Play when your hero has been hit by an attack and there is an adjacent character. The other character suffers the attack instead. This may be played on friend or foe.